# Getting port number of applications

Tags: java, networking, network-programming

I am trying to make an application where I get the port number and IP address along with some other details through which some other application such as utorrent is communicating.

Is this possible in Java. And how?

Answer (score 2):

Contrary to the comments posted under your answer, this is only possible if:

1. You know the IP:port in advance, e.g. because it is fixed, or available in an external configuration file
2. Th service is advertising itself e.g. via multicast
3. The service is registered with another fixed service such as the a Unix portmapper daemon.
4. You can discover it via SNMP.

Answer (score 0):

you can get this by looking into system calls, on linux, you can get pid of the concerning process, like ps, then get into /proc/, all file descriptors are listed there, for each fd, you can get its type, to see if it is a socket, then you can use socket diag to get its endpoint information, including src ip, port and dest ip and port.
you have to use system interfaces if you will do in java.